# refernce a cell that is a reference to another cell excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, cells

I need to create a "double reference" in an excel sheet. What I need to do is enter a date on the first sheet, then reference that date on another sheet and (heres the part I dont get), reference the 3rd cell from the 2nd cell.

I know, why not just use the first cell twice? The sheet cant work that way as the first is used for settings on the VBA app, the second saves the settings and the 3rd is where the user works so the only solution, except if someone has a solution via pure VBA, is to have a reference on a reference like a<-b<-c.

Answer (score 1):

Do it just like normal.

Go to the second cell, hit =, then go to the first tab select the date, and hit enter.

Go to the third cell and do the same thing.

Comment: Thanks but if it was that simple I'd do it, it does not work as the 3rd cell is referencing a cell that is already referenced from another cell. A = B = C, you see?

Comment: If should work with A = B, then C = B or C = A. Maybe the cell is formatted as number instead of date, and so looks different. You could upload an example excel workbook to show what you are doing?

Comment: Yip thats correct, it was the format of the 3rd cell which caused the problem.